# Clipboard binary data pastes differently

Tags: c#, .net, clipboard

I have the following code to push two binary bytes to the clipboard:

```
DataFormats.Format binaryData = DataFormats.GetFormat("BinaryData");
DataObject data = new DataObject();
data.SetData(binaryData.Name, false, new Byte[] { 0, 1 });
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data, true);
```

In my own Windows program, if I pasted the clipboard with the above data in it and ran:

```
var obj = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
```

`obj.GetData("BinaryData")` always gives:

```
{byte[2]}
    [0]: 0
    [1]: 1
```

However, when pasted in two separate other applications, the `BinaryData` object received there is always 46 bytes as follows:

```
 96 A7 9E FD 13 3B 70 43 A6 79 56 10 6B B2 88 FB 00 01 00 00 
 00 FF FF FF FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0F 01 00 00 00 02 00 
 00 00 02 00 01 0B
```

What have I done wrong?  Is an array of bytes the right class to use if I want to put some binary bytes to the clipboard?

Comment: You could convert the binary array to base64 string before copying to clipboard. and then convert it back to binary on the other end.

Comment: The other end, a third party application beyond my control, is expecting a "block" of binary bytes.

Comment: Can you use this 3rd party app to place "BinaryData" on the clipboard and the try to retrieve it in .Net app? If you can receive it, what .Net data type is the retrieved data.

Comment: Yes! It's `MemoryStream`. I used `MemoryStream` instead of Byte[] and now it works. Thanks.